# Help me write my LISP :) LISP environments, Ruby Hashes

Tags: python, ruby, programming-languages, lisp, scheme

I'm implementing a rudimentary version of LISP in Ruby just in order to familiarize myself with some concepts.  I'm basing my implementation off of Peter Norvig's Lispy (http://norvig.com/lispy.html).

There's something I'm missing here though, and I'd appreciate some help...

He subclasses Python's dict as follows:

```
class Env(dict):
    "An environment: a dict of {'var':val} pairs, with an outer Env."
    def __init__(self, parms=(), args=(), outer=None):
        self.update(zip(parms,args))
        self.outer = outer
    def find(self, var):
        "Find the innermost Env where var appears."
        return self if var in self else self.outer.find(var)
```

He then goes on to explain why he does this rather than just using a dict.  However, for some reason, his explanation keeps passing in through my eyes and out through the back of my head.

Why not use a dict, and then inside the eval function, when a new "sub-environment" needs to be created, just take the existing dict and update the key/value pairs that need to be updated, and pass that new dict into the next eval?

Won't the Python interpreter keep track of the previous "outer" envs?  And won't the nature of the recursion ensure that the values are pulled out from "inner" to "outer"?

I'm using Ruby, and I tried to implement things this way.  Something's not working though, and it might be because of this, or perhaps not.  Here's my eval function, env being a regular Hash:

```
def eval(x, env = $global_env)
  ........ 
  elsif x[0] == "lambda" then
    ->(*args) { eval(x[2], env.merge(Hash[*x[1].zip(args).flatten(1)])) }
  ........ 
end
```

The line that matters of course is the "lambda" one.

If there is a functional difference, what's importantly different between what I'm doing here and what Norvig did with his Env class?  Can someone describe to me a case where the two will deviate?

If there's no difference, then perhaps someone can enlighten me as to why Norvig uses the Env class.  Thanks :)

Comment: The best way to understand Scheme is to implement Scheme!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If variable bindings in your Lisp are immutable, then copying environments is equivalent to linking them.  But consider the following case:

```
(define main
  (lambda ()
    (define i 0)
    (define increment-i
      (lambda ()
        (set! i (+ i 1))))
    (increment-i)
    i))

(main)
```

If `increment-i`'s environment is completely independent of `main`'s (since it is a copy), the mutation of `i` will not be visible in `main` and the above code will return `0`.  If, on the other hand, the environments are linked, the return value will be `1`, as expected.

Comment: Ah, I believe that is it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My Python isn't that good and my Lisp is rather rusty but I'll take a guess about what's going on: you can't get away from pointers even in languages that claim not to have them.

The `eval` that you're talking about won't make a copy of the `dict`, it will just make a copy of the reference and you'll end up with two references (AKA variables) that refer to (i.e. point at) the same underlying object. What happens is basically a variant of this:

```
a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
b = a
a[1] = 'x'

puts a
# => ["a", "x", "c"]
puts b    
# => ["a", "x", "c"]
```

His `Env` class allows the environment to be modified inside the `eval` without modifying the outer environment while the `find` method allows you to access the outer environment without needing to know about; also, modifications will end up inside the inner environment and those changes will mask the corresponding values in the outer environment; get operations will access the local environment and the outer environment, set operations will only modify the inner environment.

I guess you could call `Env` an object level (rather than class level) facade.

I'm not sure what's wrong with your ruby implementation, looks like you're making a modified copy of the environment hash. Can you clarify "Something's not working though"?

Clarification: `Env` is a symbol table. The wrapping/redirection stuff in `find` allows you to access the outer symbol table while protecting it from new symbols being added, new symbols will only be added to the inner symbol table. `Env` essentially manages the closure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it makes logical sense.  However, I do not believe this to be the case in this instance, since AFAIK "merge" in Ruby creates a new Hash and leaves the old one untouched.  Someone correct me here if I am wrong :)

Comment: Ruby's Hash#merge does return a new Hash (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000759) so I'll take that part out of my answer. Maybe you could be a little more specific than "Something's not working though".

Comment: Well, it's not worth getting in to that...I'm not actually asking about how to fix the part of the interp. that's not working -- rather I'm mainly curious about why Norvig made that Env class.

Comment: Check my "clarification" at the end.

Comment: Would you ever need to access the outer, though?  Since the eval function passes a new hash through, the "previous" eval func will still have a copy of the old hash won't it?

Comment: If you grab a reference from the outer scope and modify it (eg: `a = array_from_outer_scope; a.push('x')` then `'x'` should still be at the end of the array when you return to the outer scope) then that modification might need to be visible in the outer scope, if you create something in the inner scope then it needs to be invisible to the outer scope.

Comment: Also, an environment capture can survive the run-time of the first evaluation. That#'s essentially what "lexical closures" is all about.